# Trying to download specific JSON from Website URL but receiving Source Page Code instead. Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping

Currently I am trying to grab a JSON off of a website (https://slapshot.gg/players/58392). I am trying to grab the JSON that is in the first row. I want my program to download the JSON, and am then looking to automatically update a Excel document or some Stat sheet with all of my stats. Currently this is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

# Set up the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Open the webpage
driver.get('https://slapshot.gg/players/58392')

# Get the HTML content
html = driver.page_source

# Parse the HTML using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Find the anchor tag with the first JSON string
anchor_tag = soup.find("a", string="JSON")

if anchor_tag:
    json_url = "https://slapshot.gg/players/58392" + anchor_tag["href"]

    # Send a GET request to the JSON URL
    json_response = requests.get(json_url)

    if json_response.status_code == 200:
        # Extract the filename from the URL
        filename = json_url.split("/")[-1]

        # Save the content to a file
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(json_response.content)

        print("Downloaded the JSON file:", filename)
    else:
        print("Failed to retrieve JSON data. Status code:", json_response.status_code)
else:
    print("JSON download link not found on the webpage.")

# Close the WebDriver
driver.quit()
```

The issue is the current output is the source page code (when you go to the website and right click and click "source page code"). I want it to save the first json.

[Here is the source page code that gets downloaded. I want the JSON of all my stats.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmHD1.png)

[Here is what the JSON link looks like in the Inspector of the website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NudqW.png)

If you have any ideas as to what is happening here and how to adjust it to work, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The data you're after is being fed in page from an API endpoint (you can find it in Dev tools -- Network tab). This is one way to get that information:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get('https://slapshot.gg/api/game/players/58392')
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['match_history'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    id  region  created     gamemode    match_type  game_stats.type     game_stats.arena    game_stats.score.away   game_stats.score.home   game_stats.winner   game_stats.players  game_stats.end_reason   game_stats.match_length     game_stats.current_period   game_stats.periods_enabled  game_stats.custom_mercy_rule
0   da8c524f-77f2-436c-86d7-77d19256d3a1    na-east     2023-06-04T05:48:22.843Z    hockey  casual  report_stats    Table Hockey    2   3   home    [{'team': 'home', 'stats': {'wins': 1, 'score'...   EndOfRegulation     300     0   False   0
1   9f4c2356-f3c8-48c9-bb7f-ed4dbd121995    na-east     2023-06-04T05:41:20.782Z    hockey  casual  report_stats    Colosseum   2   1   away    [{'team': 'home', 'stats': {'goals': 1, 'saves...   EndOfRegulation     300     0   False   0
2   2338b6db-30b1-40ce-a6db-0a5a3162db89    na-east     2023-06-04T05:35:10.740Z    hockey  casual  report_stats    Colosseum   1   2   home    [{'team': 'home', 'stats': {'wins': 1, 'saves'...   EndOfRegulation     300     0   False   0
3   4354ef30-8b33-491e-8404-cd1cf2f3450e    na-east     2023-06-04T05:29:01.688Z    hockey  casual  report_stats    Slap Stadium    2   1   away    [{'team': 'home', 'stats': {'saves': 3, 'score...   EndOfRegulation     300     0   False   0
4   797822f6-3060-49d2-80b2-b39069ce0929    na-east     2023-06-04T05:21:35.583Z    hockey  casual  report_stats    Colosseum   5   4   away    [{'team': 'home', 'stats': {'goals': 1, 'score...   EndOfRegulation     300     0   False   0
5   c89837f6-c3c1-44ae-81ab-05077a34ae02    na-east     2023-06-04T05:15:37.516Z    hockey  casual  report_stats    Slap Stadium    0   1   home    [{'team': 'home', 'stats': {'wins': 1, 'passes...   EndOfRegulation     300     0   False   0
6   25e2ad69-220c-42f5-99ff-71adf3c296a3    na-east     2023-06-04T05:06:26.395Z    hockey  casual  report_stats    Slapville   4   3   away    [{'team': 'home', 'stats': {'goals': 1, 'score...   Overtime    300     0   False   0
7   545c9d2b-a107-47c9-91d2-4e8dccbeabd2    na-east     2023-06-04T05:00:08.352Z    hockey  casual  report_stats    Slap Stadium    2   1   away    [{'team': 'home', 'stats': {'goals': 1, 'saves...   EndOfRegulation     300     0   False   0
8   5602d5b9-674b-458b-b298-6be4b513a7be    na-east     2023-06-02T01:40:44.822Z    hockey  casual  report_stats    Slap Stadium    2   0   away    [{'team': 'home', 'stats': {'score': 25, 'shot...   EndOfRegulation     300     0   False   0
9   1e1d7338-33e9-43e8-9d88-13c3dde6400f    na-east     2023-06-02T01:31:33.728Z    hockey  casual  report_stats    Table Hockey    2   5   home    [{'team': 'home', 'stats': {'wins': 1, 'goals'...   EndOfRegulation     300     0   False   0
```

​